# Отправка уведомлений ботом aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, aiogram

Пишу tg бота на базе aiogram. На данный момент у меня запускается бот и если приходит какое-то сообщение от пользователя - оно обрабатывается и выдаёт результат. Если никто не пишет, то соответственно он просто ждёт обновления и ничего не делает. А я хочу, чтобы он отправлял уведомление не в результате каких-то действий пользователя бота, а по некоторым событиям происходящим на сервере, например истёкшее время на ответ и тд. Как это можно сделать?

Пример: бот отправил запрос клиенту и у него есть 30 минут на обработку этого запроса, если в течении этого времени клиент не ответил на запрос, то ему нужно отправить уведомление об истечении запроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализировал event loop, создал в нём task и всё успешно сработало. Функция task работает с периодичностью указанной в `await asyncio.sleep(1)` не прерывая работу основного функционала бота.

```
async def task():
  while True:
      body
      await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(task())

    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score -2):

Может поможет

```
import time
from threading import *

def one(message):
    def timer1():
        time.sleep(10)   #здесь указ время
        timer = 1
        if timer ==1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Время истекло!')
    t1 = Thread(target=timer1)
    t1.start()#делаем отдельный поток с таймером
    if message == '':    #здесь мы выполняем послед. обработку сообщения
        pass
def sender(bot, message):
    a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число. У вас есть 30 минут!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(a,one)
```

Comment: Пробовал этот вариант, но он мне не совсем подошёл. Рабочий вариант кинул в ответы.